# Icon(shortcut) issues when creating executables with pyinstaller on ubuntu and linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyinstaller, shortcut

I had no problems creating the executable with pyinstaller on windows. It is a program that has a window made with tkinter and converts files. It seems that the icon of the tkinter window cannot be displayed in Ubuntu or Linux. However, the icon of the executable file in the directory or the icon in the shortcut after execution does not change. Is there any other way other than the --icon option?

Comment: Do you mean the icon above in the window or the icon of the program?

Comment: I want to be both, but  the icon above in the window seems unlikely. I wish it was the icon of the program(Includes an icon that appears in the taskbar on the left)